# Как скачать xpi файл Firefox расширения?

Tags: firefox-extension

Как скачать **.xpi** (Cross platform install) файл от *Firefox* расширения ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Переходим на сайт http://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox
2. Находим нужное расширение.
3. Нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши по кнопке *Add to firefox* и выбираем *Save link as* ("Сохранить объект как")
4. Сохраняем .xpi файл куда хотим для последующего анализа.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то если так подумать... то в файрфокс вы не скачаете .xpi файл, потому что приложение отслеживает скачивание файлов в .xpi-формате и сразу предложит его установить а не скачать.

Comment: Вы пробовали скачать так как описано в предыдущем ответе?

Comment: да.. файрфокс сразу выдаёт модально окно "установка расширения"... ну можно  кинуть ссылку в хром, и тот конечно ругаться не будет а скачает его на жёсткий диск куда укажет пользователь... далее уже можно распаковать zip-архиватором и посмотреть что за код в расширении..

Comment: У меня при клике правой кнопкой на "добавить в firefox" и выборе "сохранить объект как" успешно сохраняет дополнение как файл.

Comment: таки да.. век живи - век учись... спасибо... взяли на вооружение

Comment: @user251433, интересно, а какую версию FF вы использовали, что при попытке скачать - предлагалось установить ?